# Should I use "am" or "I'm" after already saying "I'm" in a sentence?

Tags: contractions

For example, "I'm looking forward to attending, and *am* excited to join" vs. "I'm looking forward to attending, and *I'm* excited to join."

Comment: _I'm_ is much better than _am_. Nobody would say that sentence with _am_; they might write it, but it's clearly not intended to be spoken. [_Am_ by itself is quire rare in speech.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299)

Comment: Using one of each would be mixing informal and getting on for very formal registers in a disturbing way.